# KQL Determine if datetime is in any time windows

Tags: kql

I'm looking for a timestamp of specific error in a log and so I can identify which other events occurred within N seconds of it in other tables.

I'm able to construct a table (set) of `datetime` intervals/windows, but I'm struggling to determine when a `datetime` from another table occurs within any of the intervals in the set.

```
// Create a table of time windows (interval) +/- 5 seconds of target error
let intervals = k8slogs
| where Message contains "my specific error"
| project begin=datetime_add('second', -5, env_time), end=datetime_add('second', 5, env_time)

// Show all messages within 5 seconds of "my specific error"
k8slogs
| union logs1
| union logs2
| where env_time // is in any 'window' from above query
| project env_time, Message
| order by env_time asc
```

I also tried looking into the `around()` function, but wasn't able to come up with a solution.

Here is another example below with sample data:

```
k8slogs
| env_time | message                 |
|:-------- |:----------------------- | 
| 15       | "my specific exception" |
| 45       | "my specific exception" |

logs1
| env_time | message                 |
|:-------- |:----------------------- | 
| 11       | "another error"         |
| 35       | "hello world"           |

intervals
| begin | end    |
|:----- |:------:| 
| 10    | 20     | 
| 40    | 50     | 

desired query result
| env_time | message                 |
|:-------- |:----------------------- | 
| 11       | "another error"         |
| 15       | "my specific exception" |
| 45       | "my specific exception" |
```

Comment: `env_time + 5s` / `env_time - 5s` is a neater syntax

Answer (score 1):

One technique that might work is doing joins on the time window, see the relevant [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/join-timewindow), you can do the join with the other tables and then filter based on the time interval that you are interested in, see the relevant example in the section titled "**Rewrite the query to account for the time window**"

Answer (score 1):

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution
let t1 = materialize(range record_id from 1 to  20 step 1 | extend env_time = ago(1h*rand()), Message = strcat(case(rand()<0.5, "my specific error:", "some other error:"), tostring(record_id)));
let t2 = materialize(range record_id from 1 to 100 step 1 | extend env_time = ago(1h*rand()), Message = strcat("logs1 : ", tostring(record_id)));
let t3 = materialize(range record_id from 1 to 100 step 1 | extend env_time = ago(1h*rand()), Message = strcat("logs2 : ", tostring(record_id)));
let k8slogs = view(){t1};
let logs1 = view(){t2};
let logs2 = view(){t3};
// Solution starts here
let time_window = 5s;
k8slogs
| where Message contains "my specific error"
| mv-expand i = range(-1,1) to typeof(int)
| extend env_time_bin = bin(env_time + i * time_window, time_window)
| project-away i
| project-rename error_env_time = env_time,  error_message = Message, error_record_id = record_id
| join kind=inner 
( union withsource=table (k8slogs | where not(Message contains "my specific error") | as k8slogs), logs1, logs2
| extend env_time_bin = bin(env_time, time_window) 
| project-rename log_env_time = env_time, log_message = Message, log_record_id = record_id
) on env_time_bin
| where abs(log_env_time - error_env_time) <= time_window
| project-away env_time_bin*
| order by log_env_time asc
```

| error_record_id | error_env_time | error_message | table | log_record_id | log_env_time | log_message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2022-05-18T11:53:48.7571282Z | my specific error:3 | logs2 | 33 | 2022-05-18T11:53:52.2075125Z | logs2 : 33 |
| 18 | 2022-05-18T12:05:10.2440591Z | my specific error:18 | logs1 | 48 | 2022-05-18T12:05:06.1936749Z | logs1 : 48 |
| 6 | 2022-05-18T12:11:11.8643195Z | my specific error:6 | logs2 | 15 | 2022-05-18T12:11:08.0750978Z | logs2 : 15 |
| 1 | 2022-05-18T12:38:15.4453636Z | my specific error:1 | k8slogs | 11 | 2022-05-18T12:38:12.473693Z | some other error:11 |
| 1 | 2022-05-18T12:38:15.4453636Z | my specific error:1 | logs1 | 73 | 2022-05-18T12:38:18.8940209Z | logs1 : 73 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA71TwW7aQBC9I/EPI592qQnYUaQqjW%209tpd%20gLWYwWxi71q7Aw5t%20u%20ddWwwCVWQKvWC8b6Zt%20%209GS8W8FWRAq/qpkIo0aBTpK25ge%20WoFGOwG6AtgjeVruATCcVElACGdSK0GlV6Z8onDIlgsPCunWu17BxtoYEyAKkS/CEDb%209AD4TmjWg2eeka2QSVVqRbGfcvxZSxvANvVdlQDy5QpEolO/oGX5Y3tzFENUH8A0WeqMLQOesu4/41FvmsyzVDYfMRpZZtCnFUZmU8kvvIb3aQ7L8Nw9RZUufwD1EH0i6/b%20S0o8lPX32oZIb9xpbIX9R8ruHXk2dgHQMpCPgNgCLBfzod4g18GZ54Flhb5xV5602a9ty353n%20v7i6eQF2lB4tFBYQ0obf2ERolBd7%20f43LBx0MzVJSjmSZzIEBsdGrQboQ3JUPsmuHylDffwrzhm%20YlpZmOB8filY2mcfcSC5qpVB9DjE4dGMUcnLh%20NZ/gbQ4/Vx/n0NuMeOM0%20O%201BuOLRstYnFpFpw58tTCcCdiak22raertzBWakVvxdi2GIQ5TGkrgmTskdyg87wGvUjfz1kV6X33lacCEcJrscTQAu5BKO/5KKBLY/FnPaHrXy4uym%20ZupSHjIxlrfDXbMOwso38q5rw7nDpQv/gCaMjYOVwUAAA==)

Comment: See updated answer